# How to search in a particular document library using rest API with postquery

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-search

I need to search inside a particular SharePoint (*SharePoint 2016 on premise*) document library using postquery with Rest API.
For that using **GET** call, I found a way,

```
http://{site_url}/_api/search/query?querytext='{query_text}+path:"{document_library_url}"'
```

And its working correctly.
But how can I implement this in **POST** call (using **postquery**).

**Edit**

Here is how I tried,

```
//Search button click...
function searchKBtnClick() {
    var searchKey = $("#txtSearch").val() + "+path:'{document_library_url}'";

    var searchQuery = {
        'request': {
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest' },
            'Querytext': "'" + searchKey + "'",
            'SelectProperties': {
                'results': ['DisplayAuthor', 'Title', 'Path', 'Url', 'ContentSource']
            },
            'TrimDuplicates': true,
        }
    };

    getItemsPostQuery("/_api/search/postquery", searchQuery).done(function (data) {
        var result = JSON.stringify(data.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results);
        var resultCount = data.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
        $("#txtResult").val(result);

    });

};
```

And post call,

```
//Get search result from sharepoint (POST)
function getItemsPostQuery(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

But getting no search result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem in my code,
I should have passed the *`Querytext`* attribute in this way,

```
'Querytext': $("#txtSearch").val() + "& path:{document_library_url}"
```

**instead** of this,

```
'Querytext': $("#txtSearch").val() + "+path:'{document_library_url}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `postquery`, you need to hit the `/_api/search/postquery` endpoint.

Try and modify the below code as per your requirement. Ensure that `jquery` is available before running the code:

```
var headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
}

//change url to your site 
var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/search/postquery";
var searchQuery = {
'request': {
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchRequest' },
    //your query text, change values here
    'Querytext': "'{query_text}+path:"{document_library_url}"", 
    }
};
$.ajax({
      url: endPointUrl,
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(searchQuery),
      headers: headers,
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(data){
         //use this to bind data to html
         console.log(data.d.postquery.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results);        
      },
      error:function(data){
        console.log("something went wrong");
      }
});
```

Reference - [SP Search Rest API overview](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Comment: I already tried to do it, but it returns zero search results